# Getting song lyrics using python mutagen

Tags: python, mutagen

I'm new to python. I have been practicing the use of mutagen module for mp3 metadata.

I encountered lyrics of my file on the screen.[This is the screenshot I took from my terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sL1ij.png)

this is my code:

```
import mutagen
from mutagen.flac import FLAC
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
import os
os.system('cls')
meta_date = MP3("E:\\boo\\album\\80s Rock Essentials (2021) Mp3 320kbps [PMEDIA] ⭐️\\013. Survivor - Eye of the Tiger.mp3")
print(meta_date)
meta_data = FLAC("E:\\boo\\album\ACDC - Discography (20 albums 1975 - 2008) [FLAC] [h33t] - Kitlope\\ACDC - Back in Black 1980\\AC-DC - Back in Black - 02 - Shoot to Thrill.flac")
print(meta_data)
```

For the first print call I got the lyrics on the terminal.
But for the second one I didn't get a lyrics.

I have a couple of questions:

1. What sort of lyrics is this? Can a music player use it?
2. And this string that I'm getting seems to be a tuple inside a
   dictionary but that doesn't make sense to me( It has this **USLT**
   prefix before the tuple-like part). Can someone clarify what is
   this?

thanks in advance

Comment: Can you show an example of the output you're looking at?

Comment: Not all songs have lyrics encoded in their meta-data you were lucky with the first file.

Comment: @Carcigenicate . I have added a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sL1ij.png